# How to clear export DISPLAY=some ip address

Tags: linux, display, x11

I want to clear `export DISPLAY=My IP Address` that I had given. It has botched up my X settings, so now I just want it to be reset like normal. How to clear this export parameter. Simple `set DISPLAY=` doesn't work.

Please tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: What shell are you using? Are you actually using the `set` command? That only works in some shells.

Comment: The only way to get it "like normal" is to logout and login again. Sure, `unset` will clear the variable, but it is not necessarily the same as it was before `export`ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
export DISPLAY=""
```

Usually you should have it set like this:

```
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
```

or

```
export DISPLAY="localhost:0.0"
```

Comment: If it's already exported it doesn't need to be again. Also, some shells won't let you do `export` and an assignment at the same time. You might have to do `DISPLAY=""; export DISPLAY` (if it hasn't already been exported).

Comment: Ideally I want it like before I exported anything .
My idea output is something like blank if I get set | grep DISPLAY . Which is before I set anything .
In this case it shows locahost:0.0
I want VNC to take control of this DISPLAY thing

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, knowing the shell you're using might help.

Otherwise, have you tried simply using `unset`?  The exact command would be `unset DISPLAY`, for this specific variable.

Comment: I have withdrawn my answer for unset since I missed you already answered it :)  It certainly seems like that would accomplish what was asked and I know it works in at least BASH, KSH and CSH.

Comment: I, too, missed it. But this is correct. Suggested edit: "unset DISPLAY", to match the question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
export DISPLAY=""
```

in bash should clear any value

Comment: No, that's incorrect.

Comment: Somehow even after the command , I am getting 
[[root@charlie originalnotbuildable]# export=""
[root@charlie originalnotbuildable]# echo $DISPLAY
charlie:2
I am trying to open a VNC session and somehow this charlie:2 session is not changing.